# how to use solr with a c++ application

Tags: java, c++, solr, sqlite

i' m developping an application in c++ and i wanna using solr to index sqlite database, i searched in net and i finded that i need to use JNI :
http://randr.svbtle.com/experiment-with-embedded-solr-in-java-and-c
But i finded many problems with JARS(i used the jars under \solr-4.9.0\dist\solrj-lib and \solr-4.9.0\dist  and \solr-4.9.0\example\lib\ext )
i learned that i can use JCC also,my question is what's the best solution,and if it was with JNI can you details to me how to configure solr  to be called from a c++ application and what jars i need exactly

Comment: no one can help me ???

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Solr before, but here's one way to go about this with [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) and [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). First, create this `pom.xml` build file:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>solrtest</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <header>true</header>
                    <includePath>.</includePath>
                    <linkPath>.</linkPath>
                    <preloadPath>.</preloadPath>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
                        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
                        <version>1.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As well as this `src/main/java/SolrTest.java` source file:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.solr.core.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;

public class SolrTest {
    static SolrServer createServer(String coreName) throws Exception {
        CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer();
        CoreDescriptor discriptor = new CoreDescriptor(coreContainer, coreName, new File("/some/path/", coreName).getAbsolutePath());
        SolrCore solrCore = coreContainer.create(discriptor);
        coreContainer.register(solrCore, false);
        return new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, coreName);
    }

    static class Query extends FunctionPointer {
        public @Name("query") String call(String string) throws Exception { 
            createServer(string);
            return string;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can execute `mvn package`, and after it has downloaded a whole bunch of things and built stuff for us, we're going to end up with `target/solrtest-0.jar` as well as a header file and a native library file in the `target/classes` subdirectory. Now, we can link all this together in C++ with a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "target/classes/jniSolrTest.h"

int main() {
    const char *argv[] = { "-Djava.class.path=target/solrtest-0.jar" };
    JavaCPP_init(1, argv);
    try {
        query("test");
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    JavaCPP_uninit();
}
```

That we can compile and run this way under Linux x86_64, for example, but we can do the equivalent on other platforms:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux/ target/classes/linux-x86_64/libjniSolrTest.so query.cpp -o query
$ ./query
```

And we get a proper exception from Solr:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader - JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
[main] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader - solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
[main] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader - Solr home set to '/some/path/test/'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/some/path/test/conf/', cwd=/home/saudet/solrtest
```

Something that we can fix by installing stuff for Solr...

Comment: First thanks,i tried this on windows but i have not found the libjniSolrTest and  jniSolrTest.h under the folder  target/classes/

Comment: @user3844238 Make sure you are running `mvn package` under a "developer command prompt" for C/C++, as explained on this page, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx

Comment: Sorry,i think that you miss understand me, i didn't find libjniSolrTest.lib or jniSolrTest.h under the folder target/classes/ for maven , i only found solrtest-0.jar

Comment: @user3844238 If you do not have a C++ compiler, those files will not get created. You need a C++ compiler.

Comment: I installed c++ compiler in eclipse ,and i run the project as maven install and still not have  libjniSolrTest.lib or jniSolrTest.h under the folder target/classes/  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i installed c++ compiler in eclipse,and i run project us maven install but also i don't get   libjniSolrTest.lib or jniSolrTest.h under the folder target/classes/ !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user3844238 Try not to use Eclipse. Use Maven on the command line.

Comment: @user3844238 BTW, I've just tried it on Windows, and `jniSolrTest.h` and `jniSolrTest.dll` do get generated just fine. So I don't know what to tell you other than to try to follow the instructions once again.